# what is the point of forced continuations in CosmosDB stored procedures if you need ACID transaction

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

All the javascript examples given by MS/Azure for [CosmosDB stored procedures](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/tree/master/samples/stored-procedures) force the use of continuation mechanisim that must be handled and controlled by the calling client.  ***Doesnt this defeat the purpose of having ACID atomic transactions?***

In an effort to have an ACID transaction based set of updates, I have written this much more simplified stored procedure :

```
function replace(updates) {
    var container = getContext().getCollection();
    var containerLink = container.getSelfLink();
    if (typeof updates === "string") updates = JSON.parse(updates);

    updates.forEach(
        function(doc) {
            var isAccepted = container.replaceDocument(doc._self, doc,
                function (err) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                }
            );
            if (!isAccepted) throw new Error("Execution bounds exceeded for a replace.");
        }
    );
}
```

That would seem to force feed whatever I give to to the SP to be atomic, or fail.  But after seeing all the ***vendor-provided*** examples, I just have to ask, is this a good idea??  Now, with what I am doing I really dont ever expect to hit the 5 second limit, though its possible at some points I may max out RU's, so in that case, as long as I build the Cosmos client in my back-end code to be able to work with that, will I be OK?

BTW - where is the MS doc that describes a 5-sec limit? Is there a limit to the size of the data that can be passed to the stored procdure? ( I have found by trial/error that there is a limit to the size that a SP can itself be, i believe its about 1MB or so IIRC )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That would seem to force feed whatever I give to to the SP to be
>   atomic, or fail. But after seeing all the vendor-provided examples, I
>   just have to ask, is this a good idea??

In my opinion, your current plan is time-consuming and expensive for RUs. You need to pass the data which is need to be updated,before that,you need to prepare such data(query from database or assembled in your own application).

I suggesting you using the [bulk update example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-js-server/blob/master/samples/stored-procedures/update.js) of stored procedure.Based on the document,the database engine in Azure Cosmos DB supports full ACID (Atomicity, Consistency, Isolation, Durability) compliant transactions with snapshot isolation.

[image]

> where is the MS doc that describes a 5-sec limit? Is there a limit to
>   the size of the data that can be passed to the stored procdure?

Not found such limitation statements in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-write-stored-procedures-triggers-udfs),but still have many clues in this [blog](https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/06/27/cosmos-db-stored-procedures-handling-continuation/). Anyway, SP has [time out situation](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/7426303-i-get-microsoft-azure-documents-requesttimeoutexc), you can't ignore that. As you mentioned in your question,you need to manage continuation token if the update data is huge.Still could find example in the [blog](https://vincentlauzon.com/2018/06/27/cosmos-db-stored-procedures-handling-continuation/).